# Output SQL result to JSON (row wise based on a specific column) [Microsoft SQL Server]

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have 3 tables, below three and I am sharing my SQL Query to print a JSON from SQL

**SEC_USER**, **USER_PROFILE_ENTRY**, **SEC_FOLDER**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN FIRST_NAME > '' AND LAST_NAME > ''
            THEN CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME)
            ELSE LOGIN_NAME
            END AS displayName,
            FIRST_NAME AS givenName ,LAST_NAME AS surname,
            'user' AS extension_user_type,
            identities = (SELECT (CASE WHEN LOGIN_NAME LIKE '%@%.%' THEN 'emailAddress' ELSE 'userName' END) as signInType,
            innr.LOGIN_NAME AS issuerAssignedId
            FROM SEC_USER
            innr WHERE
            innr.LOGIN_NAME = ottr.LOGIN_NAME FOR JSON AUTO),
            extension_timezone = COALESCE((select ABBREVIATION from TIME_ZONE
            where OLSON_TIME_ZONE_URN = (SELECT INT_VAL FROM USER_PROFILE_ENTRY WHERE PROFILE_KEY = 'TimeZone' and ottr.USER_ID = USER_PROFILE_ENTRY.USER_ID)),''),
            extension_locale = COALESCE((select STRING_VAL from USER_PROFILE_ENTRY
            where PROFILE_KEY = 'Culture' and ottr.USER_ID = USER_PROFILE_ENTRY.USER_ID),''),
            extension_tenant = COALESCE((select XML_DATA.query('/Columns/Column[@Name=''TENANT_MANAGER_TENANT_ID'']/text()')
            from SEC_FOLDER where ottr.FOLDER_ID = SEC_FOLDER.FOLDER_ID),'')
            from SEC_USER ottr where USER_TYPE = 'U' and SYSTEM <> 1  
            FOR JSON PATH,
            ROOT('users')
```

This is my SQL query result,

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Dennis Law",
      "givenName": "Dennis",
      "surname": "Law",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "dennislaw@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-IN",
      "extension_tenant": "Team1"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Geroge West",
      "givenName": "Geroge",
      "surname": "West",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "gwest"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "PST",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "Team2"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Shaggy Nate",
      "givenName": "Shaggy",
      "surname": "Nate",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "NST",
      "extension_locale": "en-AF",
      "extension_tenant": "Team1"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see in the JSON there is one key named **extension_tenant** which has values like Team1, Team2, Team3 and so on.

When I run my above query I get a single row query result which has my JSON, below is the image, The above JSON is beautified version of below result.

[image]

How can I create a separate JSON for based on DISTINCT **extension_tenant**,

I want to know if there is a way I can break this JSON based on extension_tenant and output it in rows below rows based on extension_tenant.

Suppose all with extension_tenant = Team1 will be stored in a separate JSON result,

example : for all with Team1

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Dennis Law",
      "givenName": "Dennis",
      "surname": "Law",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "dennislaw@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-IN",
      "extension_tenant": "Team1"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Shaggy Nate",
      "givenName": "Shaggy",
      "surname": "Nate",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "NST",
      "extension_locale": "en-AF",
      "extension_tenant": "Team1"
    }
  ]
} ";
```

and for all with extension_tenant as Team2

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Geroge West",
      "givenName": "Geroge",
      "surname": "West",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "gwest"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "PST",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "Team2"
    }
  ]`
} ";
```

please let me know if there is a way, also if you want some more data please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to modify your statement like this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
   -- The current statement, without the FOR JSON part
   SELECT ...
   --FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('users')
)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.extension_tenant, t2.json
FROM cte t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT 
      displayName, 
      givenName, 
      surname, 
      extension_user_type, 
      JSON_QUERY(identities) AS identities, 
      extension_timezone, 
      extension_locale, 
      extension_tenant
   FROM cte
   WHERE extension_tenant = t1.extension_tenant
   FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('users')
) t2 (json)
```

Note, that you need to use `JSON_QUERY()` to prevent escaping the `identitites` JSON. The following simplified example is a working solution:

```
;WITH cte AS (
   SELECT displayName, extension_tenant, identities
   FROM (VALUES
      ('Dennis Law', 'Team1', '[{"signInType": "userName", "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"}]'),
      ('Geroge West', 'Team2', '[{"signInType": "userName", "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"}]'),
      ('Shaggy Nate', 'Team1', '[{"signInType": "userName", "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"}]')
   ) ottr (displayName, extension_tenant, identities)
   --FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('users')
)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.extension_tenant, t2.json
FROM cte t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT displayName, extension_tenant, JSON_QUERY(identities) AS identities
   FROM cte
   WHERE extension_tenant = t1.extension_tenant
   FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('users')
) t2 (json)
```

Result:

```
extension_tenant    json
Team1               {"users":[{"displayName":"Dennis Law","extension_tenant":"Team1","identities":[{"signInType": "userName", "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"}]},{"displayName":"Shaggy Nate","extension_tenant":"Team1","identities":[{"signInType": "userName", "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"}]}]}
Team2               {"users":[{"displayName":"Geroge West","extension_tenant":"Team2","identities":[{"signInType": "userName", "issuerAssignedId": "Shaggynatealpha"}]}]}
```

Comment: this is exactly how I was supposed to do it! Thank you marking as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need nothing but a `WITH..AS` Clause in which keep your current query except the last two lines and then filter out by `extension_tenant` such as

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN FIRST_NAME > '' AND LAST_NAME > '' THEN
              CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, ' ', LAST_NAME)
             ELSE
              LOGIN_NAME
           END AS displayName,
           FIRST_NAME AS givenName,
           LAST_NAME AS surname,
           'user' AS extension_user_type,
           identities = (SELECT (CASE
                                  WHEN LOGIN_NAME LIKE '%@%.%' THEN
                                   'emailAddress'
                                  ELSE
                                   'userName'
                                END) as signInType,
                                innr.LOGIN_NAME AS issuerAssignedId
                           FROM SEC_USER innr
                          WHERE innr.LOGIN_NAME = ottr.LOGIN_NAME
                            FOR JSON AUTO),
           extension_timezone =
           COALESCE((SELECT ABBREVIATION
                      FROM TIME_ZONE
                     WHERE OLSON_TIME_ZONE_URN =
                           (SELECT INT_VAL
                              FROM USER_PROFILE_ENTRY
                             WHERE PROFILE_KEY = 'TimeZone'
                               and ottr.USER_ID = USER_PROFILE_ENTRY.USER_ID)),''),
           extension_locale =
           COALESCE((SELECT STRING_VAL
                      FROM USER_PROFILE_ENTRY
                     WHERE PROFILE_KEY = 'Culture'
                       and ottr.USER_ID = USER_PROFILE_ENTRY.USER_ID),''),
           extension_tenant =
           COALESCE((SELECT XML_DATA.query('/Columns/Column[@Name=''TENANT_MANAGER_TENANT_ID'']/text()')
                      FROM SEC_FOLDER
                     WHERE ottr.FOLDER_ID = SEC_FOLDER.FOLDER_ID),'')
      FROM SEC_USER ottr
     WHERE USER_TYPE = 'U'
       AND SYSTEM <> 1
)
SELECT * 
  FROM t
 WHERE extension_tenant = 'Team1' -- or 'Team2'
```

Comment: I think in your solution, it will build for only if you select Team1 or Team2. Maybe be in where you can nest like where extension_tenant = (select * from table...)